# Finding the probability of the coordinates of a point at random.

Tags: probability, statistics, lebesgue-measure, coordinate-systems, uniform-distribution

Let $(X,Y)$ be the coordinate if a point chosen uniformly at random on $[0,1]^2$. Find the probability that $|Y-X| \leq 0.29$.

I think that this question may involve Lebesgue, but unsure how to start.

Comment: Just draw a picture of the "good" region inside the unit square.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @lulu just to confirm my answer below would be correct?

Comment: Yes, this looks good.  And you are certainly correct that the complementary area is easier to compute.

Answer (score 2):

you can start doing a drawing of your problem

[image]

your requested probability is the purple area...better:  your probability is the ratio between purple and total area, which is 1 in this case

Comment: Thank you, definitely makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Answer based on sketch suggestion from lulu]

Finding the area of the non-shaded region is easier, so I calculated this and the the area of the unit square is 1, hence area of shaded region is 1-non-shaded? i.e. = 0.4959

Comment: Yes correct. See my answer